# Got an error \end{thebibliography} while I used \bibliographystyle+\bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, compiling, ieeetran

I was about to finish the LaTeX article for IEEE when I encountered an error in compiling the .bib file (called tacklingbib). This is part of the code for inserting bibliographic information

```
\bibliographystyle{ieeetran}
\bibliography{BibTeX/tacklingbib}
```

It was in the third stage of the process (1.pdfLaTex[successful], 2.BibTex[successful], 3. pdfLaTeX[error!]) that I received the following error:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 973--974
(./Tackling_cite.bbl
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
l.24 \end{thebibliography}
```

I didn't use thebibliography, but I received its error! I deleted all the citations in the text unless the first one to see if there was any error in any of the citation commands. But the error repeated. This is the only cite in my .bib file:

```
@article{delen\_effects\_2014,
    title = {Effects of interactivity and instructional scaffolding on learning: {Self}-regulation in online video-based environments},
    volume = {78},
    issn = {03601315},
    shorttitle = {Effects of interactivity and instructional scaffolding on learning},
    url = {https://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S0360131514001511},
    doi = {10.1016/j.compedu.2014.06.018},
    language = {en},
    urldate = {2023-02-13},
    journal = {Computers \& Education},
    author = {Delen, Erhan and Liew, Jeffrey and Willson, Victor},
    month = sep,
    year = {2014},
    pages = {312--320},
}
```

It has only 15 lines and I wonder where the error was pointing by l.24! I'd appreciated it if anyone can help.

Comment: In your code you haven't explicitly written a `thebibliography` environment, but when you ran BibTeX on your document, BibTeX generated it for you (following the style given in `\bibliographystyle`). This automatically generated `thebibliography` environment lives in the `.bbl` file and is read in by your document. The line number in the error refers to the `.bbl` file. You haven't given a full example, but the `\_` in your entry key `delen\_effects\_2014` will cause errors. You don't need to and should not escape underscores there. ...

Comment: ... Make that read `delen_effects_2014`. Delete the `.bbl` and `.aux` files and try again.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Can you confirm that the file `\jobname.bbl` -- where `\jobname` is the name of the main tex file -- contains just `\begin{thebibliography}` and `\end{thebibliography}` directives? You mention that the BibTeX run was "successful" -- what's in the file `\jobname.blg`?

Comment: Dear moewe, I had to replace _ with \_ (in the .bibtex file) to escape the error in the early stage of compilation for bibliography insertion. Removing it hinders the advancement of the process.

Comment: Mico, I didn't use \begin{thebibliography} + \end{thebibliography}.  Because the IEEE format recommended using either that environment OR \bibliography{} and I chose the second option.

Comment: Mr. Moewe, I followed your recommendation. I made that expression read delen_effects_2014. I deleted .bbl and .aux. Still, I am receiving l.24 \end{thebibliography}
 error.

Comment: Sorry, without a small (self-contained) example document that reproduces the error with as little code as possible (and is compilable for us, i.e. does not reference files we dont have) I can't say anything more. The `\_` are bound to cause trouble, but that's the only problematic bit of the code you have shown so far. If you still have issues after replacing `\_`s with `_`s, the problem must lie elsewhere.